# C# How to create a label onClick on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, label

What I am looking for is for the user to 
 1. click on the canvas
 2. a new label show up and the user can enter text.
 3. When the user clicks elsewhere or hit enter the labels is finished editing.

This is what I have so far...

```
        private void DrawingCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
        var point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Content = "start typing";
        //lbl.Left = location.X;
        //lbl.Top = location.Y;
        //lbl.Focus = Boolean.TrueString;
        canvas.Children.Add(lbl);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: We cannot edit in Label. You will have to use TextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Canvas x:Name="cnvs" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="cnvs_MouseLeftButtonUp"  Background="Transparent"></Canvas>
```

```
  private void cnvs_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
        var point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox() {Width=80,AcceptsReturn=false };
        canvas.Children.Add(txtBox);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txtBox, point.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(txtBox, point.Y);
        txtBox.Focus();
    }
```

I hope this will help.

**UPDaTE**:

```
var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
        var point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox() {AcceptsReturn=false ,BorderThickness=new Thickness(0)};
        Binding b = new Binding("Text") { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self) };
        txtBox.SetBinding(TextBox.WidthProperty, b);
        canvas.Children.Add(txtBox);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txtBox, point.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(txtBox, point.Y);
        txtBox.Focus();
```

Comment: Alright Its almost entirely there. Since I'm using a textbox know how do I get rid of the border?  And Have the width equal to what I type in? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the textbox width to Double.NaN. This will give you an "Auto" width. To get rid of the border, set the textbox's borderthickness to 0. See below:

```
 private void cnvs_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
        var point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        var txtBox = new TextBox() { Width=Double.NaN, AcceptsReturn=false }; // auto width
        txtBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0); // no border
        canvas.Children.Add(txtBox);
        Canvas.SetLeft(txtBox, point.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(txtBox, point.Y);
        txtBox.Focus();
    }
```